# Firebase RealTime Database Security Rule in Angular and .NET Core

Tags: angular, firebase, asp.net-core

I have 2 applications. One is .net backend apis and the second one is angular web application Both are connected to firebase. There are no Security Rule implemented on firebase database

I write data into firebase from backend api (.net core application). The angular application has subscribed the node of firebase. Whenever a new data has been detected in firebase the angular application refersh the data of page. I have subscribed to firebase using following code in my angular application.

```
this.firebaseDb.list(firebasenode).valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
//refreshes my list 

   });
```

The code the is being used in .net for patch data is

```
  var fireBaseDbObj = new FirebaseDB(this.Uri);
  var firebaseRoot = fireBaseDbObj.Node(rootNode);

  var response = firebaseRoot.Patch(jsonData);
   return response.Success;
```

Now my firebase is giving the warning of no rules implemented
How can I implement the rules in .net and angular 
I created the rule on database in firebase console. But not my code stopped working and saying permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

rules should be implemented in Firebase Auth i guess. You should be able to distinguish call from angular and .net by means of authentication. based on that, probably you should forbid write access for angular and allow to .net
if only i understood you correctly.

Comment: How do I pass auth from angular or .net to firebase so that firebase can decide ?

Comment: Use Firebase auth API